# What is the difference between JDE plugin and Java plugin for Eclipse

Tags: ide, blackberry

I am completelty new to the BB development.

I want to start development of BlackBerry application.

I am confused how to start? And what plugins have to download and from which link?

And bit confused about the JDE plugin <--> Java plugin for Eclipse

Which I have to download for development?

Can any one explaine the above things?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDE and eclipse plugin are same other than, JDE has only debug mode, but the eclipse has both debug and run mode. I am using eclipse for several years, so I feel comfortable in using eclipse. I recommend eclipse because, it is more developer friendly when compared to JDE.

Comment: is it neccessary to download JDE prior to download "BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.0.0.67" for eclipse ?
because i cant build the .cod,.jad,.jar files which is required to run on simulator/device.

Comment: No not necessary. You can download the eclipse with blackberry plugin from the following link and you can find the installation guide on the same page. Enjoy coding.

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaeclipseplug.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Karthikeyan that eclipse has a more feature rich environment plus it can incorporate other plugins such as cvs, svn, mysql etc.

Sometimes it can take more configuration to get everything set up right properly.  If you want to get your code up and running quickly without any configuration, I would highly recommend using the JDE.

Glen